Measure temperature of raw image in DJI SDK
I'm learning how to use the DJI SDK in Python scripts to analyse the content of thermographies (radiometric JPGs, R-JPG).
According to the docs, calling the SKD with the "measure" option should produce a "global temperature value image which pixel type is INT16 or FLOAT32."
.\dji_irp.exe -s .\DJI_blablabla.JPG -a measure -o measure.raw

I've done so, which has produced a binary file I can read with Python. This file contains a list of integer values which is 655360-elements long. Values seem to come in pairs: values at odd positions range from 1 to 252, while values at even positions can either be 1 o 0.
temps = subprocess.call(['./dji_irp.exe', '-s', path_file, '-a', 'measure', '-o', 'measure.raw'])

with open('measure.raw', 'rb') as f:
    file_contents = f.read()
    byte_array = np.frombuffer(file_contents, dtype=np.uint8)

print(len(byte_array))
#655360
print(byte_array[:10])
#[69  1 69  1 69  1 78  1 73  1]

When separated into two arrays and reshaped as 640x512 they look like this:
print(byte_array[0:40:2])
# [ 69  69  69  78  73  78  73  65  51  56  65  65  65  69  69  65  61  29 233 178]
print(max(byte_array[0::2]))
# 252
print(min(byte_array[0::2]))
# 1
plt.imshow(byte_array[0::2].reshape((512, 640)), cmap='magma')


print(byte_array[1:40:2])
# [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
print(max(byte_array[1::2]))
# 1
print(min(byte_array[1::2]))
#0 
plt.imshow(byte_array[1::2].reshape((512, 640)))


The second image look like a mask of the first one, but I don't know how to interpret the values from the first one, because such values don't look like temperatures to me, not even in Fahrenheit degrees.

What exactly are the values of the first one? What is the range it spans? Please edit that information into your question

@Marsroverr I've just added the data you requested, thanks for your help

The odd position values seem to be from 0-255, which is likely relative to either the range of the sensor or the min/max absolute temperature of the image. (I'm guessing the latter) Is there any attached metadata that could help determine what temperature values to map to each end? The binary values also do seem to be a mask, likely this is based on some kind of threshold you can configure somewhere.

Also - Have you looked at this page? https://lyuhaitao.github.io/dji_thermal_sdk/core_dji.html#dirp_measure

Also downloaded the SDK just now to look at the docs for you and see if I can't puzzle this out and write you a definitive answer

Wrote an answer - Any SDK provided by DJI is frustratingly underdocumented and opaque and I don't have the actual thermal data to test so let me know if it works

Based on my understanding of the bundled readme and documentation - The dji_irp.exe that you're using is the bundled sample code and the measure functionality you're using is just meant to output an image and not be used for actual measurements. You'll have to write custom code in order to do what you're trying to accomplish.
I've found this Python library you can include and have it grab the DLLS from utility\bin\windows\release_x64 in the SDK, that then exposes the SDK functions in your Python code. Otherwise you'll have to follow the SDK's bundled readme's instructions on writing your own C code:

Project configuration:

Add <custom application path>/3rdparty/tsdk/include to your include path.
Link <custom application path>/3rdparty/tsdk/lib/<libdirp.so or libdirp.dll> to your project.


Source Code Development:

Include the <custom application path>/3rdparty/tsdk/include/dirp_api.h
in your source code.
Call TSDK APIs to perform infrared image processing.


Build project with MSVC or GCC.

Either way the function you're looking for is dirp_measure_ex, which the documentation describes as doing the following:

Measure temperature of whole thermal image with RAW data in R-JPEG. Each FLOAT32 pixel value represents the real temperature in Celsius.


Thanks for your answer @Marsroverr! Do you think you can provide a snippet of code that I can try? In the meantime I'll try this approach myself and come back with more feedback. Thanks!

@J.Maria I'm hesitant to edit code snippets into my answer as I can't test them myself, if you can somehow provide a raw image I can write and test an MRE

unfortunately, I don't think I'm even legally allowed to share the files. I'll try to implement the answer and see if it works.
